# Try to Read Base64 from Content fails

Tags: c#, base64

I try to read a base64 encoded file from a image.
I parsed the document and got the base64 content extracted, but when I try to decode the information into a byte array I got a error, that the base64-string that I deliver is corrupted. 
I try to extract a base64 encoded audioFile from a JPEG.

I checked the string and can't find the issue, maybe you guys can help me?

The FormatException is happening in:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64AudioString);
```

Attached please find the code:

```
string path = @"D:\Projects\200308 - ImageReader\ConsoleApp1\";

// --- Read JPG ---
byte[] jpegBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path + "IMG_20190905_132110.vr.jpg");
var asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(jpegBytes);

// --- Check for GAUDIO-Infos ---
var start = asString.IndexOf("GAudio:Data=") + 13; // asString.IndexOf("<x:xmpmeta");
var end = asString.IndexOf("\"", start); // asString.IndexOf("</x:xmpmeta>");

if(start != -1 && end != -1)
{
    // Parse Base64 Part
    string base64AudioString = asString.Substring(start, end - start);
    //base64AudioString = base64AudioString.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/').PadRight(4 * ((base64AudioString.Length + 3) / 4), '='); // Validate
    //File.WriteAllText(path + "IMG_20190905_132110.vr.jpg.base64string", base64AudioString); // Export string into file

    // Write Byte Array
    byte[] base64ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64AudioString);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path + "IMG_20190905_132110.vr.jpg.gaudio", base64ByteArray);
}
```

Here is also the sample file that I try to parse:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n7dE5U0YBRKiQzH4TovT2acSubuLt_u2

**EDIT:** I figured out that the encoding need to be:
Encoding.Default.GetString(jpegBytes); // not Encoding ASCII

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the string it's failing on?  It's likely not actually Base64, such as not being the correct length (multiple of 4) or contains invalid characters.

Comment: first I have to confess that I don't know anything about that audio format. More information from your side would be helpful, I didn't find anything. But I had a look into the file: when you open that jpeg in notepad++ and search for `GAudio:Data=` you'll notice that there's first some base64 data, then `ÿáÿÅhttp://ns.adobe.com/xmp/extension/ 2A1FDC3384D267CA2F17CF49E1B3317F h¯Ø `Ì` and then more base64 data. That's why you can't just decode the whole part between start and end. But as I don't know that format, I don't know what to take and put into a file to get a playable audio file.

Comment: Hey guys
Thanks for the response.
The URL could be the corruption you are right.

I take my information from the google documentation, because this file is created by the Google Cardboard Camera App that puts some more information inside the file including audio.

Here is the link to the documentation. At the end of the page you will find a example of the of the information that I like to parse:
https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/cardboard-camera-vr-photo-format#gaudio

Comment: The audio is saved in general as M4A, the Mime type is defined in the image, and I will later take it into account for setting the right file extension when the data are extracted.

I have a working base64 extraction as a comparison that I extracted with a different tool. I will upload it to the post, when I'm at home.

Thanks so far!

Comment: @Zero: I found a validation method to make it fit to the right length using: base64AudioString = base64AudioString.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/').PadRight(4 * ((base64AudioString.Length + 3) / 4), '=');

Comment: Please find the working B64 version from the external tool attached:
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ag2LjIuDOMjzj2nUXTVXeOatuWQPBFSD)

Comment: And here the exported from my programm:
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jDBPihFEyBDbwLSIGv00Y5cgKDG7G7v6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need some smaller corrections.

- instead of

  ```
  var asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(jpegBytes);
  ```

  you have to use ASCII encoding:

  ```
  var asString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jpegBytes);
  ```

  that's the main reason why you got a lot of unreadable output with asian characters instead of base64 code.
- then you have to search for the end as:

  ```
  var end = asString.IndexOf("</rdf:RDF>", start) -4;
  ```
- at least your example picture contains a string like this:

  ```
  ÿáÿÅhttp://ns.adobe.com/xmp/extension/ 2A1FDC3384D267CA2F17CF49E1B3317F h¯Ø Ì
  ```

  mixed under the base64 codes (occurring 7 times!), that needs to be removed:

  ```
          var rubbish = "http://";
          var indexRubbish = base64AudioString.IndexOf(rubbish);
          while (indexRubbish >= 0)
          {
              base64AudioString = base64AudioString.Remove(indexRubbish - 4, 79);
              indexRubbish = base64AudioString.IndexOf(rubbish);
          }
  ```
- and finally you need padding (You had this already in your code but commented out)

  ```
          base64AudioString = base64AudioString.PadRight(4 * ((base64AudioString.Length + 3) / 4), '=');
  ```

The full code is then:

```
string path = @"D:\Projects\200308 - ImageReader\ConsoleApp1\";

// --- Read JPG ---
byte[] jpegBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path + "IMG_20190905_132110.vr.jpg");
var asString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jpegBytes);

// --- Check for GAUDIO-Infos ---
var start = asString.IndexOf("GAudio:Data=") + 13;
var end = asString.IndexOf("</rdf:RDF>", start) -4;

if (start != -1 && end != -1)
{
    // Parse Base64 Part
    string base64AudioString = asString.Substring(start, end - start);
    var rubbish = "http://";
    var indexRubbish = base64AudioString.IndexOf(rubbish);
    while (indexRubbish >= 0)
    {
        base64AudioString = base64AudioString.Remove(indexRubbish - 4, 79);
        indexRubbish = base64AudioString.IndexOf(rubbish);
    }

    base64AudioString = base64AudioString.PadRight(4 * ((base64AudioString.Length + 3) / 4), '='); // Validate

    byte[] base64ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64AudioString);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path + "IMG_20190905_132110.vr.mp3", base64ByteArray);
}
```

The result is a playable mp3 file.

Comment: Thank you very much jps. You made my day. That was it! And thanks for the nice step by step explanation. I tried it now with another file and needed to add a extra remove for a the string "/ at the end. So I think I will continue and add some more garbage checks and a mine-type interpretation for a solid export.

Comment: By the way. the hint with notepad++ was super good. I used sublime before, but it was alreay interpreting to much so I couldn't figure out the things you found. So I installed notepad++ and can see the format properly.

Comment: you're welcome. Was a quite interesing "puzzle" to solve ;-)  NP++ is a very useful tool for the developer.

Comment: @StephanSch only thing I wonder is where do all these http:// links come from, that destroy the base64 code?

Comment: Good point. I downloaded the images directly from my Google Photos account. I will compare the file with the one that is recorded on the smartphone. Maybe the download from the website destroyed it.

Comment: I worked a bit more on the script and I figured out that the encoding needed to be: Encoding.Default.GetString(jpegBytes); Because on writing the same data again, I got some unknown characters.

Comment: And I'm still on investigating the riddle with the links, because it turned out, when I replace the existing base64 data with a different mp3 file the image is ok, but the playback on the google photos platform is not working. So I have the feeling that the links are part of informatios, that needed to be put it. (I following the question on a different ticket now.

Comment: thanks for the updates.But putting the link just randomly on several positions in a base64 encoded section doesn't seem to make much sense. Let me know if you find out more.